# Unknown provider: LovesFilterProvider <- LovesFilter

Tags: angularjs

Why is  "function MsgController($scope, lovesFilter) {" the word "lovesFilter" has to be lower case. If I use "LovesFilter" I would get error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LovesFilterProvider <- LovesFilter <- MsgController
```

Shouldn't it be "LovesFilter" to match the .filte('loves,LovesFilte)?
Here is the code:

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html ng-app='MsgApp'>
            <head>
                <title>Custom Filters</title>
                <script src="angular.js"></script>
                <script>
                /*
                custom filter

                */
                (function () {
                    'use strict';

                    angular.module('MsgApp', [])
                    .controller('MsgController', MsgController)
                    .filter('loves', LovesFilter)
                    .filter('truth', TruthFilter);

                    MsgController.$inject = ['$scope', 'lovesFilter'];
                    function MsgController($scope, lovesFilter) {
                    $scope.stateOfBeing = "hungry";

                    $scope.sayMessage = function () {
                        var msg = "Dog likes to eat healthy snacks at night!";
                        return msg;
                    };

                    $scope.sayLovesMessage = function () {
                        var msg = "Dog likes to eat healthy snacks at night!";
                        msg = lovesFilter(msg)
                        return msg;
                    };

                    $scope.feedDog = function () {
                        $scope.stateOfBeing = "fed";
                    };
                    }

                    function LovesFilter() {
                    return function (input) {
                        input = input || "";
                        input = input.replace("likes", "loves");
                        return input;
                    };
                    }

                    function TruthFilter() {
                    return function (input, target, replace) {
                        input = input || "";
                        input = input.replace(target, replace);
                        return input;
                    }
                    }

                })();
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Custom Filters</h1>
                <div ng-controller='MsgController'>
                Original: {{sayMessage()}} <br/>

                <!--
                    replaces:
                    original:Dog likes to eat healthy snacks at night!
                    new:Dog loves to eat healthy snacks at night!
                -->
                Loves: {{ sayLovesMessage() }} <br/>

                <!--replace 
                    original:Dog likes to eat healthy snacks at night!
                    new:Dog likes to eat cookie snacks at night!
                    -->
                Truth: {{ sayLovesMessage() | truth: 'healthy' : 'cookie'}} <br/>

                <!--
                    original:Dog loves to eat healthy snacks at night!
                    replace:DOG LOVES TO EAT COOKIE SNACKS AT NIGHT!

                -->
                BIG TRUTH: {{sayLovesMessage() | truth: 'healthy' : 'cookie' | uppercase}}
                <div>
                    <button ng-click="feedDog()">Feed Dog</button>
                    <br/>
                    <img ng-src="dog_{{stateOfBeing}}.jpg" />
                </div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Well no. Your filter is named 'loves', not 'Loves'. And the error confirms it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because while you are registering a filter like `.filter('loves', LovesFilter)`, the name you are giving to your filter is **loves**. So, when you are injecting this in the controller it should be **lovesFilter** and not **LovesFilter**. As per documentation you can see `<filterName>Filter`. And the name of your filter is **loves**. If you want it to be resolved in uppercase, use `.filter('Loves', LovesFilter)`